# Why does Sitecore CMS UI trigger OWASP captcha when combined with Cloudflare?

Tags: security, cdn

We have a Sitecore 8.2.4 installation and the Production environments sits behind Cloudflare.

On the CM instance, our Content Editors keep getting interrupted by a (broken) captcha dialogue box from Cloudflare. This seems to happen for some popup dialogues and also the Experience Editor is broken with a similar popup displayed.

[image]

[image]

When sensitivity is set to "LOW" the Captcha will still show. When set to "OFF" the captcha will not show.

I am wondering if anyone would know which OWASP rule exactly is Sitecore triggering that might be causing the Captcha to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After speaking to Sitecore Support I received the following answer. I hope this can help someone else experiencing the same situation.

- Sitecore client/backend does not support running behind a CDN especially when caching and OWASP ruleset are enabled.
- Sitecore has registered a feature request for the product so that it can be considered for future implementation. To track the future status of this request, please use the reference number 199315.
- In the meantime, please consider not using OWASP ruleset, since it breaks your solution behaviour.

Comment: This other post is also very relevant and contains great information. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10819/waf-support-with-sitecore-experience-platform