# WAF support with Sitecore Experience Platform

Tags: azure, security

We are looking for a Web Application Firewall (WAF) solution for our Sitecore CMS implementation, because we are an Azure shop we specifically wanted to use the WAF feature on the Azure AppGateway resource.

Per Sitecore's knowledge base article, it appears that this is not a supported feature. https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/682999

- Does anyone know why this isn't supported?
- Is it the case that no WAF products are supported?
- Has anyone had experience with Sitecore support pushing back due to the presence of a WAF?

Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

**Update:** Currently WAF is supported in diagnostic mode only for v8.2 and 9.0

**In version 9.1 WAF is supported for the CD servers.**

More information can be found here: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/en/using-azure-application-gateway-to-secure-your-content-delivery-server.html

---

Below are the list of OWASP rules that are causing problems, and as you can see there are two that cannot be disabled so we there is no work around for WAF right now.

Breaks Site: 942200  942260  942330  942340  942350  942370
Breaks CMS (when going into a piece of content): 941180  942100  942110  942130  942150
Can't be removed in WAF: 949110  980130

Comment: For anyone interested, the rules 949110 and 980130 relate to the "total inbound anomaly scores" and are rated as *critical*.  The Security Rules are listed in a GitHub repo at https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/tree/e4e0497be4d598cce0e0a8fef20d1f1e5578c8d0/rules

Comment: Does Sitecore have an official page which shows this as not supported? Does Sitecore have any recommendations on an alternative WAF?

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot document everything what we don't support. There is no recommendation for any firewalls I am aware of.

Comment: Is it supported in Sitecore 9.1? I do not see anything in the release notes.

Comment: Yes, in version 9.1 WAF is supported for the CD servers. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Does this mean that WAF is only supported for CD servers? I can not find any documentation in the sitecore docs that cm server arent supported. (Using 9.1.0 XP0)
Found only this docs: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/en/using-azure-application-gateway-to-secure-your-content-delivery-server.html but they dont mentioned any about cm systems.

Comment: Yes, WAF is supported for the CD servers only.

Comment: What is "diagnostic" mode and have there been any updates to 8.2 support for WAF since 2019?

Answer (score 3):

We tried WAF prevention mode in 9.0.2 (9.0.1 should also work) and made it work in the end. `Imp: Sitecore 9.1 won't magically fix it as MS itself is struggling to expose variables to customize Azure WAF parameters.`

First time webforms submit failed as 942130 rule blocked it: "Matched Data: ADGTypeValue>Terms found within ARGS:fieldsets.fields.customParams.value: Terms of Use
"

so we disabled this rule and the ones below. Keep in mind that 'post' goes through a log checking of its content(body), especially if there is a form that accepts upload(pdf or pics). It is pointless to check all the contents of upload, so we disabled the inspect request body.

[image]

We only need this for CD. So just do proper testing and monitor the WAF logs(first in detection mode, in PROD). Run this query in Monitor-> Logs and chill.

```
search in (AzureDiagnostics) ResourceType == "APPLICATIONGATEWAYS" and 
Resource == "<RG NAME>" | sort by TimeGenerated desc
| where Category == "ApplicationGatewayFirewallLog" 
| where Message like "SQL Injection Attack" 
| where clientIp_s == "<IP of machine doing testing>" //optional
```

EDIT: Azure WAF 2.0 can have exceptions rules just like windows firewall